# Does Dropbox store my password on my computer?

Tags: dropbox, passwords, mac, password-recovery

About a year ago I changed my Dropbox password and lost access to the email address my Dropbox account was associated with in the same day due to a rather acrimonious end to my employment.

I almost immediately forgot the password without writing it down but not before signing on with my computer. I am still able to use Dropbox with this computer and even get on the site but I can't change the email address or password to it because I don't have either of them any longer.

Unfortunately Dropbox ignores my repeated requests for assistance.

So I was thinking maybe the password is stored somewhere on my Mac. I have looked through the application files as much as I know how to navigate and have not seen anything related to a login yet. I also looked in my keychain and it wasn't there either.

Does anyone have any ideas how to find this? I don't want to get a new account. I have a lot of free space and a sweet grandfathered rate for my upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

There is and there should be no way to recover your password, since this would mean it could be hacked. At least it should be this way if Dropbox is taking security serious.

They can never be sure if the person requesting access to the account is the same person that created the account since the only link is your Email and Password.

Getting a new account, maybe with the old rate will be the only way, since then Dropbox can be sure that you only have access to data that is yours because its on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it were stored it would be in an encrypted form which will be pretty difficult to decrypt and recover your password in plain text.

You should email Dropbox support in detail and explain in detail of how you lost access. They are the only people who can help you here to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

For me, [this page](https://www.dropbox.com/account) offers a "change email" link (after login). I did not test it, beacuse I do not want to change my email right now. Does this not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

No, the password is not stored on the PC. Dropbox access is tokenised. What methods have you tried to contact them? Have you submitted a ticket through their [support portal](https://www.dropbox.com/support)? Also, I have seen people with a similar problem to yours get help through their [forums](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/English/ct-p/English), it might be worth posting there.

Answer (score 0):

> I am still able to use Dropbox with this computer and **even get on the site**...

If you are able to log into dropbox.com, your password is also stored in your browser. Every browser has a "view saved passwords" option.

Comment: This is simply wrong. None of my browser store passwords, yet here I am logged in - using a password manager and receiving a cookie after login.

Comment: @PatrickR., imho there is not much difference between standalone password manager and the one built into a browser. The point is the browser gets the password in plain text from somewhere to log into the website.

Comment: There is a lot of difference between a password manager and unsecured, direct saving in the browser. But even if there wasn't, my point is that while the OP might have had a valid session in her browser, that doesn't mean that the password can be recovered - it only means there still was a valid cookie.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. There is a probability that user still has session cookie which hasn't yet expired.